# Can't convert string have new line characters to JSONArray

Tags: java, json, string, exception, converters

I'm have problem with create JSONArray from string have new line characters example:

```
 String text = "[" +
            "'test line 1 \n" +
            "test line 2 \n" +
            "line 3', " +
            "'255.255.255.240' ," +
                "'<Not Set>'" +
            "] ";
 JSONArray tmpArray = new JSONArray(text);
```

it will have exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: Unterminated string at character 15 of ['test line 1
```

is there way fixed the problem?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just escape the `\` as in `\\n`, and then it will work. Also note you need to escape `'` also.

```
 String text = "[" +
        "'test line 1 \\n" +
        "test line 2 \\n" +
        "line 3', " +
        "'255.255.255.240' ," +
            "'<Not Set>'" +
        "] ";
```